# Step by step instruction to run offline OpenStreetMaps

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm trying to run offline version of OpenStreetMaps on my server.

I have an ASP.NET MVC app which displays OSM map.
So far I run the quick start example from OpenLayers.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([
            37.41, 
             8.82
        ]),
        zoom: 4
    })
});
```

The thing is I need everything offline. I already downloaded planet-latest.osm.bz2 file, but I'm confused what are next steps.

I read I have to render tiles now, from osm file, right? I tried to use Mapnik/Maperetive to achieve this but it didn't go well.
I also don't know how to connect all there things together.

@EDIT1
Do I have to render all tiles before use(approx. 20TB) or can I render tiles on demand (when someone will use map)?

Comment: All your questions have already been answered multiple times on the Internet. Also this is pretty offtopic for StackOverflow. Search for OpenStreetMap offline and read about the various solutions (raster tiles vs vector tiles, pre-rendered vs rendering on the fly, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just clarify a couple different bits of terminology for you:

- **OpenStreetMap** provide raw data of where roads, buildings, sea, etc. are
- **[Mapnik](https://mapnik.org/)** is one of many tile servers
- **Tile Servers** require raw data, and tile styles and generate images (usually)
- **Tile Styles** are usually XML, you can generate these using CartoCSS and tools like TileMill
- **[CartoCSS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/CartoCSS)** is similar to web CSS, but modified slightly to make more sense in the context of mapping
- **[TileMill](https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/)** is one of many tools for writing and previewing CartoCSS

The information above may not be *necessary* for you, because Open Tile Server has some sensible defaults and is probably the best place for you to look: https://opentileserver.org/